# Building a list inside a list - Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. How can I store the following data as a list inside of another list?

```
inputList = [[{'timestamp': '2017-10-28T00:00:00.000Z', 'open': '0.051430', 'close': '0.051210', 'min': '0.050583', 'max': '0.051955', 'volume': '30953.184', 'volumeQuote': '1584.562468339'}, {'timestamp': '2017-10-29T00:00:00.000Z', 'open': '0.051191', 'close': '0.049403', 'min': '0.048843', 'max': '0.053978', 'volume': '42699.215', 'volumeQuote': '2190.567660769'}],[{'timestamp': '2017-10-28T00:00:00.000Z', 'open': '0.063390', 'close': '0.072991', 'min': '0.062544', 'max': '0.073524', 'volume': '199636.573', 'volumeQuote': '13427.870355674'}, {'timestamp': '2017-10-29T00:00:00.000Z', 'open': '0.072840', 'close': '0.073781', 'min': '0.069449', 'max': '0.090833', 'volume': '284448.623', 'volumeQuote': '21687.962221794'}]]
```

Output should be:

```
outputList = [[0.051210, 0.049403],[0.072991, 0.073781]]
```

and what I have so far is:

```
[0.051210, 0.049403, 0.072991, 0.073781]
```

I use the following code:

```
insideLoop = []
outputList = []
for list in inputList:
    for i, v in enumerate(list):
        closing = float(v['close'])
        insideLoop.append(closing)
    outputList.append(insideLoop)
```

To be noted that the inputList can be several lists long.

Any solution to this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using your code actually produces `[[0.05121, 0.049403, 0.072991, 0.073781], [0.05121, 0.049403, 0.072991, 0.073781]]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple list comprehension

```
result = [[x['close'], y['close']] for x, y in inputList]
print(result)
# - > [['0.051210', '0.049403'], ['0.072991', '0.073781']]
```

**Update**

For undetermined number of elements in sublist, use nested list comprehension

```
result = [[x['close'] for x in y] for y in inputList]
print(result)
# - > [['0.051210', '0.049403'], ['0.072991', '0.073781']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
s = [[{'timestamp': '2017-10-28T00:00:00.000Z', 'open': '0.051430', 'close': '0.051210', 'min': '0.050583', 'max': '0.051955', 'volume': '30953.184', 'volumeQuote': '1584.562468339'}, {'timestamp': '2017-10-29T00:00:00.000Z', 'open': '0.051191', 'close': '0.049403', 'min': '0.048843', 'max': '0.053978', 'volume': '42699.215', 'volumeQuote': '2190.567660769'}],[{'timestamp': '2017-10-28T00:00:00.000Z', 'open': '0.063390', 'close': '0.072991', 'min': '0.062544', 'max': '0.073524', 'volume': '199636.573', 'volumeQuote': '13427.870355674'}, {'timestamp': '2017-10-29T00:00:00.000Z', 'open': '0.072840', 'close': '0.073781', 'min': '0.069449', 'max': '0.090833', 'volume': '284448.623', 'volumeQuote': '21687.962221794'}]]
new_s = [[float(i['close']) for i in b] for b in s]
```

Output:

```
[[0.051210, 0.049403], [0.072991, 0.073781]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = []

for a in inputList:
    res = []
    for i in a:
        res.append(i['close'])
    result.append(res)

print(result)
```